# Connect Azure Blob Storage JSON data using SSMS

Tags: json, sql-server, ssms, azure-blob-storage

I need to store Azure Blob storage JSON data inside SQL Server database. I am searching step by step guide for that.

Comment: What have you found so far? There are a few ways to do it. I prefer this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017 but you need to know that name of the blob.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is very common,i provide 2 main ways for your reference to implement your needs.

1.Azure Data Factory.

You could use Copy Activity in ADF to transfer data from Azure Blob Storage into SQL DB.There are very detailed guides in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-dot-net).

2.Bulk insert T-SQL.

You could use T-SQL to load files stored in Azure Blob Storage into SQL DB.Please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/files-from-azure-blob-storage-to-sql-database/) and this [guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52061.t-sql-bulk-insert-azure-csv-blob-into-azure-sql-database.aspx).